# JS append not working when using a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have this code:

```
success: function (result) {
   var textoTipos = $('.cargarTextosTipo');
                      
   for (var selecttipos of textoTipos) {
       selecttipos.append(`<option value="0">Hello this is a test</option>`);

   // some code

   }

}
```

My problem is that inside loop `` selecttipos.append(`<option value="0">Hello this is a test</option>`); `` is not working and it is not appending to a select component but this way worked but this is not the way I am looking for:

```
 success: function (result) {
    var textoTipos = $('.cargarTextosTipo');
   textoTipos.append(`<option value="0" > Hello this is a test </option>`);

}
```

How do I make it work using a loop? this is the way I want because I have to go through each select node and do some stuff later rather than applying to all select stuff.

Comment: Hi! Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/). Or at a **minimum**, show us the HTML of the page as it is prior to the code above.

Comment: (As a side note: Adding several options with the same `value` and text seems a bit odd.)

Comment: I am not telling my entire problem, I just resumed it.

Comment: If you mean you summarized it, yes, you did -- too much, so much so that we can't reliably answer it. Again, please provide an [mre] or at **minimum** show us the HTML of the page as it is prior to the code above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When looping `textoTipos` you get plain HTML elements.
You should wrap `selecttipos` to be jQuery object: `$(selecttipos)`

```js
function success(result) {
   var textoTipos = $('.cargarTextosTipo');
                      
   for (var selecttipos of textoTipos) {
       $(selecttipos).append(`<option value="0">Hello this is a test</option>`);

   // some code

   }
}

$(document).ready(success);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="cargarTextosTipo"></select>
<select class="cargarTextosTipo"></select>
<select class="cargarTextosTipo"></select>
<select class="cargarTextosTipo"></select>
```

Comment: This one did the trick. Next time I am going to post detailed problem. I just summarized this one too much. but worked.  `$()` was missing for me

Comment: @EthernalHusky - I assumed because you didn't mention or show an error message that you were doing this in an environment that supported the newish [`append` method of the DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append) (not jQuery). Glad Justinas was able to help. Please be sure to always include (via copy and paste) any errors you're seeing in the devtools console. Happy coding!